# How do I set parallelism count for the storm bolts?

Tags: java, apache-storm

I'm running an 8 core machine with 4 worker slots; I had 10 bolts. As per my knowledge, each bolt uses a single executor by default. I.e.: my 8 core has only eight executors.  Is that right or wrong?  If right, how do I set the parallelism-count for my 10 bolts?  If wrong, what’s the right way to set parallelism?

Comment: Cannot answer this question right now; thus I add a comment: You can run more than 8 executor (an executor is just a thread and you can have more threads than cores). Thus, you can run each Bolt with any parallelism you like. However, you should consider how much CPU each executor actually consumes -- in general the question about the best parallelism for each Bolt is very hard to answer!

Comment: thanks for your comment !! Hope I may get the answer  :) @ Matthias J. Sax

Comment: Can you add the concrete error message. Is it a Java exception? If yes, please add the full stack trace.